# <process_gl_state_enables:519> "Invalid enum" 0xde1 - AdrenoES20 - LIBGDX

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx

I'm debugging my game and I get this error. what could be the issue here ? I eliminated the possible culprits based on the searches I've done :  I had some  `Gdx.gl20.glDisable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D)` lines and I've eliminated them all but still no luck . I get the same error. this only happens on the 4.4.2 kernel not on 4.2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't like the following command either because it doesn't need it:

```
Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Eliminating it from the render thread made the errors disappear and I got  a 1FPS gain .